# Android App freezes only on one device, and only sometimes. (With output)

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, freeze

So, I've got an android game, that draws stuff on canvas. So basically, it's looping the whole time:

```
onDraw(Canvas c){
    doThis();
    doThat();
    drawThis(c);
    drawThat(c);
    invalidate(); //calls onDraw again
}
```

And it works perfectly and smooth on any device, except for the Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge. I have one my self, and also a friend of mine experiences the exactly same thing on his S6 Edge. (The problem would most likely also occur on the normal S6, as it includes almost the same hardware, but I never ran the app on that device).

The problem: The application runs smooth for first, but when running for some minutes, it just freezes forever (or at least 20minutes, then I give up), until TouchWiz asks to stop the task.
So the UI does not respond, it just freezes, nothing else happens, but I was able to catch the console output on my device now:

```
W/Resources: Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=3 r=0x7f0d003c}
W/Resources: Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=3 r=0x7f0d003d}
D/Activity: performCreate Call Injection manager
I/InjectionManager: dispatchOnViewCreated > Target : com.dj.gravitydodge.FullscreenActivity isFragment :false
D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled mFloatingMenuBtn : null
D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled return false
D/SRIB_DCS: log_dcs ThreadedRenderer::initialize entered! 
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLES_mali.so
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
I/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI protection enabled for context ,  &this =0x7f7ef05e60 ,&mEglDisplay = 1 , &mEglConfig = 2130264752
D/OpenGLRenderer: Get maximum texture size. GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE is 8192
D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [2560x1440]-format:1
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@33c468cf time:304260522
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
[... No output for a while ...]
I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 227691(7MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 10% free, 58MB/65MB, paused 622us total 113.736ms
[Freeze]
```

Specs of the device:

```
CPU: Samsung Exynos 7420 (4x1,5GHz & 4x2,1GHz) [Btw the only Octacore CPU, the app was tested on]
GPU: Mali-T760
RAM: 3GB DDR4
[More info: http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_s6-6849.php]
```

If you have any idea what the problem's cause is, or how I can fix it, please answer.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It's tested on more than a hundred devices, it only froze on the S6E thought. (The application is already on the PlayStore) And the code is over 700 lines long, so I believe uploading it fully, would be a problem :/

Comment: http://pastebin.com/5DJVwnjR (I don't know if my code is understandable, as there are some shortenings, and the code is not perfect either, but I would be thankful, if you threw a look at it. thx) The most relevant functions are in there. drawLevel and getCollision might be the most dangerous ones.